# android html data parsing

Tags: html, android, xml, parsing, dom

Hi guys suddenly I have no experience with java and html parsing and I really need it...(possibly from http://www.uefa.com/teamsandplayers/teams/club=52280/domestic/index.html)

I want a simple way to convert an html website to xml document(fetch,convert,parse) or an easy alternative way to do it...

ps:if you know any alternative FREE resource of football(soccer) data tell it...

Comment: Why wouldn't displaying the data as a website work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the site is of doctype xhtml:

> DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"

shouldn't it be xml / parseable already? I haven't tried, but just an assumption

But why don't you take the rss feeds from
http://www.uefa.com/news/rssfeeds/index.html

That's clearly XML (RSS). And you'll find an xml parser here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

I use that one for fetching twitter rss feeds.